# Styling Polymer paper-dropdown-menu and menu using host

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, polymer-1.0

At the top of my document, I can style all the paper drop down menus and menus contained inside using root, but I would like to style a single one instead of all of them.

The paper-dropdown-menu is contained inside a paper-scroll-header-panel.

```
<paper-toolbar>

  <div class="flex title" style="font-family: Georgia, Verdana, Helvetica; letter-spacing: 2px;">My title</div>

</paper-toolbar>

 <template id="userOptionMenu" is="dom-bind">

    <style>

        :host {
             --primary-text-color: #1B5DCF;
             --paper-input-container-label: {
                 color:white;

             }
             --paper-input-container-underline: {
                visibility:hidden; 
             }
        }


    </style>


    <paper-dropdown-menu id="label" label="Name" noink no-animations>
        <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">

            <paper-item>Profile</paper-item>
            <paper-item>Sign Out</paper-item>


        </paper-menu>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>

 </template>


<div class="content">

  <content size="100">

    test<br/>
    test<br/>
    test<br/>
    test<br/>
    test<br/>
    test<br/>
    test<br/>

  </content></div>

   </paper-scroll-header-panel>

</body>
```

Comment: Please explain what you meant by "I would like to style a single one instead of all of them".

Comment: So you have a global style but want to override it for a single dropdown component? You could try hack it and throw `!important` at the end of each css line on the component you want to override...

Comment: Justin XL & Ricky - I'd like to style one drop down menu, but not the rest. Polymer is supposed to be able to do this by using multiple shady/shadow DOMs.

The example that I posted does not work, so I'm not sure how adding !important would do anything. It only works if I use :root with the css specified at the top of the file.

Comment: For now I resolved this with element ID's instead of host